# How to parse WCF binary response manually (xml)

Tags: wcf, binary

I need to parse WCF binary response. The reason is that I have no contract nor metadata I can just call wcf service with parameters using WebClient. What I'm getting now is binary response with xml inside but when I want to deserialize it with BinaryFormatter and load xml document, it gives me an error because of leading data. Is there some class which can do this for me?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your contract and binding that you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for responses. Actually I ended up following this blog post (Fiddler plugin):

http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/11/fiddler-plug-in-for-inspecting-wcf.html

there is also a link to source code:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfbinaryinspector

hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for something similar and I came across https://github.com/waf/WCF-Binary-Message-Inspector

It may help you out.